How to fix alignment and size of three backgrounds in my diagram?
Could anyone help me make all three backgrounds the same size and align both at the top and bottom? I have been trying for several hours but have only been able to align two of them at the bottom.

 \documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}
    


\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,backgrounds

 }
    
    \begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{tikzpicture}[mynode/.style = {rectangle, draw, align=center,
            text width=5cm,fill=white,
            inner xsep=1mm, inner ysep=2mm, rounded corners},
                        my arrow/.style={single arrow, draw,minimum height=0.7cm, minimum width=0.4cm},  % Reduced arrow height and width,
            rotate border/.style={shape border uses incircle, shape border rotate=#1},
            font=\sffamily]
            
\node[mynode, label={[name=lab, align=center]Step1}] (inner1) {box1};

\node[mynode, below=2mm of inner1, align =center] (justbelow1) {
box2
};

\node[mynode, below=2mm of justbelow1, align =center] (justbelow1b) {
box3
};
\node[mynode, below=2mm of justbelow1b, align =center] (justbelow1c) {
box4
};

%
\node[right=1cm of inner1, mynode, label={[name=cal]Step 2}] (inner2) {box1};
\node[mynode, below=2mm of inner2] (justbelow2) {box2 \\
content
};
\node[mynode, below=2mm of justbelow2, align =center] (justbelow2b) {
box3
};

%
\node[right=1cm of inner2, mynode, label={[name=img]Step 3}] (inner3) {box1};
\node[mynode, below=2mm of inner3] (justbelow3) {box2};
\node[mynode, below=2mm of justbelow3] (justbelow3b) {
box3 \\
content
};

%
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \node[fit={(lab) (inner1) (justbelow1c)}, draw,fill=blue!20, inner sep=0.5mm] (outer1) {};

    \node[fit={(cal) (inner2) (justbelow3b.south-|inner2.south)}, draw, fill=blue!20] (outer2) {};

    
    \node[fit={(img) (inner3) (justbelow3b)}, draw, fill=blue!20] (outer3) {};
\end{scope}

\path (outer1) -- (outer2) node[pos=0.45,my arrow]{}
      (outer2) -- (outer3) node[pos=0.45,my arrow]{};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


Can you please take out packages not needed here? E.g. novices may  need to install them just for nothing, just to try your code. Thank you

With use of the chains library` the code is much shorter and simpler:
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%
\usepackage{lipsum}                              % for dummy text
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,
                chains,
                fit,
                positioning,
                shapes.arrows
                }

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure*}[!t]
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 2mm and 15mm,
  start chain = going below,
A/.style = {single arrow, draw,
            minimum height=7mm, minimum width=4mm},  
F/.style = {draw, fill=blue!20, 
            inner xsep=2mm, inner ysep=4mm, yshift=2mm,
            fit=#1},
N/.style = {draw, rounded corners, fill=white,
            text width=\dimexpr\textwidth/3-42mm/3\relax, 
            inner xsep=1mm, inner ysep=2mm,
            align=center,
            on chain},
every label/.append style = {font=\small, anchor=north},
font = \sffamily          
                   ]
\node (n11) [N] {box1};
\node (n12) [N] {box2};
\node (n13) [N] {box3};
\node (n14) [N] {box3};

\node (n21) [N, right=of n11] {box1};
\node (n22) [N] {box2\\ content};
\node (n23) [N] {box3};

\node (n31) [N, right=of n21] {box1};
\node (n32) [N] {box2};
\node (n33) [N] {box3\\ content};

\scoped[on background layer]
{
    \node (f1)  [F=(n11) (n14), label=north: Step 1]    {};
    \node (f2)  [F=(n21) (n14.south -| n21),
                                label=north: Step 2]    {};
    \node (f3)  [F=(n31) (n14.south -| n31),
                                label=north: Step 3]    {};
}
\node[A, right=2mm] at (f1.east) {};
\node[A, right=2mm] at (f2.east) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure*}
\lipsum\lipsum

\end{document}

Which gives

Edit:
In the case, that you like to have image in one column, you need to replace \textwidth with \columnwidth and reduce inner xsep and font size accordingly:
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%
\usepackage{lipsum}                              % for dummy text
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,
                chains,
                fit,
                positioning,
                shapes.arrows
                }

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 2mm and 13mm,
  start chain = going below,
A/.style = {single arrow, draw,
            minimum height=7mm, minimum width=4mm},  % Reduced arrow height and width,
F/.style = {draw, fill=blue!20, 
            inner xsep=1mm, inner ysep=4mm, yshift=2mm,
            fit=#1},
N/.style = {draw, rounded corners, fill=white,
            text width=\dimexpr\columnwidth/3-35mm/3\relax, %
            inner xsep=1mm, inner ysep=2mm,
            align=center,
            on chain},
every label/.append style = {font=\small, anchor=north},
font = \small\sffamily          
                   ]
\node (n11) [N] {box1};
\node (n12) [N] {box2};
\node (n13) [N] {box3};
\node (n14) [N] {box3};

\node (n21) [N, right=of n11] {box1};
\node (n22) [N] {box2\\ content};
\node (n23) [N] {box3};

\node (n31) [N, right=of n21] {box1};
\node (n32) [N] {box2};
\node (n33) [N] {box3\\ content};

\scoped[on background layer]
{
    \node (f1)  [F=(n11) (n14), label=north: Step 1]    {};
    \node (f2)  [F=(n21) (n14.south -| n21),
                                label=north: Step 2]    {};
    \node (f3)  [F=(n31) (n14.south -| n31),
                                label=north: Step 3]    {};
}
\node[A, right=2mm] at (f1.east) {};
\node[A, right=2mm] at (f2.east) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\lipsum

\end{document}



With ext.positioning-plus documentation tikz-ext and this post How to vertically stack a node above another fitted node? The package author writes:

With above = … of -() you not only place a node above of 
but also make it as wide as . (Alternatively, | makes it as high
and + makes it as wide and high.)

With \node[right=0.9cm-\pgflinewidth of +(outer1), draw, fill=blue!20] (outer2) {}; we create a node of the same height and same width.
right=0.9cm for 0.9cm=1cm-2*inner sep
I added node distance=2mm and 1cm, to lighten the code a little
code
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/730754/how-to-fix-alignment-and-size-of-three-backgrounds-in-my-diagram
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{
  % positioning,
  ext.positioning-plus,%<< added
  fit,
  backgrounds
  }   
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[
  mynode/.style = {
    node distance=2mm and 1cm,% 1cm and 1cm by default
    rectangle,
    draw,
    align=center,
    text width=5cm,
    fill=white,
    inner xsep=1mm,
    inner ysep=2mm,
    rounded corners
    },
  my arrow/.style={
    single arrow,
    draw,
    minimum height=0.7cm, 
    minimum width=0.4cm},  % Reduced arrow height and width,
  rotate border/.style={
    shape border uses incircle, 
    shape border rotate=#1},
  font=\sffamily]               
\node[mynode, label={[name=lab, align=center]Step1}] (inner1) {box1};
\node[mynode, below=of inner1] (justbelow1) {
box2
};
\node[mynode, below=of justbelow1] (justbelow1b) {
box3
};
\node[mynode, below=of justbelow1b] (justbelow1c) {
box4
};
% %
\node[right=of inner1, mynode, label={[name=cal]Step 2}] (inner2) {box1};
\node[mynode, below=of inner2] (justbelow2) {box2 \\
content
};
\node[mynode, below=of justbelow2,] (justbelow2b) {
box3
};

\node[right=of inner2, mynode, label={[name=img]Step 3}] (inner3) {box1};
\node[mynode, below= of inner3] (justbelow3) {box2};
\node[mynode, below= of justbelow3] (justbelow3b) {
box3 \\
content
};
%
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \node[fit={(lab) (inner1) (justbelow1c)}, draw,fill=blue!20,
    inner sep=0.5mm%<<<  for 0.9cm=1cm-2*0.5mm
    ] (outer1) {};
    % \node[fit={(cal) (inner2) (justbelow3b.south-|inner2.south)}, draw, fill=blue!20] (outer2) {};
    % \node[fit={(img) (inner3) (justbelow3b)}, draw, fill=blue!20] (outer3) {};
    \node[right=0.9cm-\pgflinewidth of +(outer1), draw, fill=blue!20] (outer2) {};
    \node[right=0.9cm-\pgflinewidth of +(outer2), draw, fill=blue!20] (outer3) {};        
\end{scope}

\path (outer1) -- (outer2) node[pos=0.45,my arrow]{}
      (outer2) -- (outer3) node[pos=0.45,my arrow]{};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



Getting them to be the same size is manual work, but the misalignment is being caused by inner sep=0.5mm on your first node inside the scope, just get rid of it. Related to the size problem, changing all below=2mm to below=0.5mm on the first block seems to do the job. Here's the code:
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,backgrounds}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
                mynode/.style = {rectangle, draw, align=center,
                text width=5cm,fill=white,
                inner xsep=1mm, inner ysep=2mm, rounded corners},
                my arrow/.style={single arrow, draw,minimum height=0.7cm, minimum       width=0.4cm},
                rotate border/.style={shape border uses incircle, shape border rotate=#1},
                font=\sffamily
            ]
        
        \node[mynode, label={[name=lab]Step 1}] (inner1) {box1};
        \node[mynode, below=0.5mm of inner1] (justbelow1) {box2};
        \node[mynode, below=0.5mm of justbelow1] (justbelow1b) {box3};
        \node[mynode, below=0.5mm of justbelow1b] (justbelow1c) {box4};
        
        %
        \node[right=1cm of inner1, mynode, label={[name=cal]Step 2}] (inner2) {box1};
        \node[mynode, below=2mm of inner2] (justbelow2) {box2 \\ content};
        \node[mynode, below=2mm of justbelow2] (justbelow2b) {box3};
        
        %
        \node[right=1cm of inner2, mynode, label={[name=img]Step 3}] (inner3) {box1};
        \node[mynode, below=2mm of inner3] (justbelow3) {box2};
        \node[mynode, below=2mm of justbelow3] (justbelow3b) {box3 \\ content};
        
        %
        \begin{scope}[on background layer]
            \node[fit={(lab) (inner1) (justbelow1c)}, draw,fill=blue!20] (outer1) {};
            
            \node[fit={(cal) (inner2) (justbelow3b.south-|inner2.south)}, draw, fill=blue!20] (outer2) {};
            
            \node[fit={(img) (inner3) (justbelow3b)}, draw, fill=blue!20] (outer3) {};
        \end{scope}
        
        \path (outer1) -- (outer2) node[pos=0.45,my arrow]{}
        (outer2) -- (outer3) node[pos=0.45,my arrow]{};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}


Unfortunately I don't want to change to below=0.5mm as it does not look nice.
How can I manually set them algin?
